# Access SQL - Joins on multple tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I have come across a Join Error in Access SQL, when using multiple "ON" criteria's. I am unable to perform an ON clause on 2 different tables, for example:

```
select * 
from
(((A 
left join B on a.id = b.id)
left join c on c.id = b.id)
left join D
on (d.id = b.id) and (d.id = a.id)
```

That final join statement causes an error because I link table D on table B first, and then link Table D on Table A. If I choose to instead link table D on Table B again, then it resolves. However, I need to join it this way due to the certain data I need to link Table D on from both tables.

How can I more efficiently structure my query to achieve my results?

Comment: I think the problem is your parentheses, not your joins or `on` clauses. Remove all of the parentheses and rerun. Also... are you getting an error? If so it would be very helpful to share that.

Comment: Choose a database with more conformant `JOIN` syntax.  That is a bit tongue in cheek, but MS Access is rather limited.  You should also update the question.  All your joins are on the same fields, so it the multiple condition is not necessary.  That makes it hard to make a real suggestion.

Comment: @JNevill is right.  You have 5 left parentheses and 4 right parentheses

Comment: Well... I may be half-right. Access is a clown when it comes to joining tables as Gordon suggested. I would think all of this left joining should be allowed though as I only ever ran into issues mixing INNER and LEFT in Access. But it's been a long time since I've been in access except to export data to put it into a proper database.

Answer (score 0):

you may try this select * from A left join B on a.id = b.id left join c on c.id = b.id left join D on d.id = b.id and d.id = a.id

Comment: Please format your answer correctly and give additional explanation to your query if you can.

Answer (score 0):

It's somewhat difficult to tell what you're trying to do exactly, but most likely, this is what you want:

```
select * 
from
(((A
left join B on a.id = b.id)
left join C on c.id = b.id)
left join D on d.id = a.id)
```

Since you're trying a LEFT JOIN, there is no reason to link multiple ids to eachother.